# Toolbar overlay hidden under system UI in YouTube player fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using a [`YouTubePlayerFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) in my activity, and attempting to overlay the player with an app bar (aka action bar) when the player is in fullscreen. I'm following the guidelines and example in the YouTube Player API "Overlay ActionBar Demo" [sample application](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) and YouTubePlayerFragment documentation (more detail below).

All of this worked fine when I was extending from [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and using the core [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html). But when I switch to using [`AppCompatActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) with the support [`Toolbar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), a few issues arise:

- The Toolbar is laid out under the status bar and navigation bar
- The player no longer plays when the Toolbar is on top of it

It seems as though the player fullscreen mode used to treat the action bar as part of the system UI (along with the status bar and navigation bar), in terms of positioning and overlay, but no longer does so with the Toolbar.

**Any thoughts on why this is happening or how I can use the Toolbar to properly overlay the YouTube player in fullscreen mode?**  I realize the Toolbar is just another view and I could probably force it to resize and reposition under the status bar, and I could set up a [listener for system UI changes](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html) and show and hide my Toolbar accordingly, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner fix that I'm missing.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Toolbar overlay YouTube player]

More detail: I was able to reproduce this behavior in the "Overlay ActionBar Demo" sample app (`ActionBarDemoActivity`), with the following changes:

- Extend `AppCompatActivity`
- Change import from `android.app.ActionBar` to `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`
- Add Toolbar to layout

  ```
  <FrameLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <view
          class="com.examples.youtubeapidemo.ActionBarDemoActivity$ActionBarPaddedFrameLayout"
          android:id="@+id/view_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

      ...

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500" />

  </FrameLayout>
  ```
- Change the theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and add `windowActionBarOverlay`

  ```
  <style name="OverlayActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Set the Toolbar as the action bar in `onCreate()`

  ```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  ```

Note that the sample app also does the following (I didn't change these):

- Implement [`YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener)
- Extend the layout and set padding when not in fullscreen so that content displays below Toolbar

  ```
  @Override
  public void onFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
      viewContainer.setEnablePadding(!fullscreen);
      ...        
  }

  public static final class ActionBarPaddedFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

      public void setEnablePadding(boolean enable) {
            paddingEnabled = enable;
            requestLayout();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      int topPadding =
          paddingEnabled && actionBar != null && actionBar.isShowing() ? actionBar.getHeight() : 0;
      setPadding(0, topPadding, 0, 0);

      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
  ```
- Set YouTube player fullscreen control flag

  ```
  player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
  ```
- Handle config changes

  ```
  <activity
      ...
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      ...
  </activity>
  ```

Comment: did you find any solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is a bug.  I filed a new bug report for the layout problem, and added a comment to an existing report about the support ActionBar/Toolbar being treated as an illegal overlay.

- [Toolbar overlay hidden under system UI in YouTube player fullscreen](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8033)
- [With AppCompat theme on older devices, ActionBar is detected as an illegal overlay](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7742)

In the meantime, as a workaround I'm doing the following:

**Layout issue**

As Troy suggested, I added `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the Toolbar XML. This fixed the layout in fullscreen, but caused padding to be added to the Toolbar when leaving fullscreen ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pb0L.png)). I added logic to the `onFullscreen(boolean)` method to remove the Toolbar padding (`toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)`) but this unfortunately still shows white space in place of the padding, which disappears when the layout is next redrawn (e.g., when clicking an item, starting the player, etc). I'm still a little stumped on how to properly set the layout/padding, but the current workaround will do for now.

**Illegal overlay issue**

Given that showing the Toolbar will pause the YouTube player in fullscreen, I've added logic to only show the Toolbar when the player is already paused. This isn't ideal, as it forces the user to pause the player to see the Toolbar, but it's the best option I can think of.

In `onFullscreen(boolean)`, if we enter fullscreen and the player is playing, the Toolbar is hidden.

```
public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {    
    mFullscreen = isFullscreen;

    if (isFullscreen && youTubePlayer.isPlaying()) {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

When setting up the player (in `onInitializationSuccess()`), I added a listener to show and hide the Toolbar on play and pause:

```
youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() { 
        if (mFullscreen) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() { 
        if (mFullscreen) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will solved your issue.
To hide navigation bar and toolbar

```
   public void fullScreenCall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { //lower api
        View v = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

to back normal mode

```
public void normalScreenCall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your toolbar in your XML file.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to fix the first issue (Toolbar hidden under system UI), but not the second (player still stops when Toolbar is on top).

Comment: I hit send too soon, and meant to add the following:

It also introduces some weird behavior when exiting fullscreen mode. When adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the Toolbar XML, exiting fullscreen adds padding on top of the Toolbar ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ZkQuvid.png)).  And when instead adding `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` to the style, it adds white space on top and to the right of the Toolbar ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/aJnVuiY.png)).